# Cannot enable Java in Safari (or any other browser) in OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, java, safari

I have the following running on my Mac:

- OSX Yosemite (10.10.2)
- Java version 8 update 31
- Safari 8.0.4

I am unable to run any Java applet on Safari. I have added multiple sites to the exception lists (in System Preferences -> Java Control Panel -> Security), but it has not changed anything.

I also don't see anything related to Java in Safari preferences:

[image]

When I try to run a Java applet, it says, `Error. Click for details.`, and when I do, this is what I get:

[image]

I've tried Chrome and Firefox as well, and this is the common error they give me:

[image]

Whatever I do, I cannot allow for Java applets to be run on any browser.

Comment: Did you try adding 140.113.239.214 to the exception list under System Preferences -> Java -> Security ?

Comment: Didn't work. It asked me permission to run it, I said ok, and then it didn't load again. It says Error, click for details again. But this time, the error is `NullPointerException`: There was an error while executing the application. Click "Details" for more information.

Comment: Huh. NullPointerException sounds like an issue with the actual Java program you're trying to run. Do you have an IT group you can contact?

Comment: Ok, tried it with another java applet from another site. It worked, but safari keeps on crashing. Works perfectly well with chrome, though.

Comment: To Safari, Java counts as a plug-in. So you may need to click the "Website Settings…" button for plug-ins, find Java in the list of plug-ins, and add websites to the whitelist.